# Menu overlay positioning issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I've got a flyout menu on a site that I'm building.  I'm using a UL nested within the LI.  In Firefox it's working beautifully but IE breaks it. (The Pants & Shorts link is the only one with a flyout so far)

Here's the site (a work-in-progress so it's not quite all there):
http://epalla.com/bogeypro/featured/covert-cooler.html

If I set:

```
.bogeypro_catmenu ul li {
position: static;
}
```

the submenu does become visible in IE, but in IE6 it flys at the top of the page (absolute positioning is NOT relative to the LI) and in IE7 it still doesn't fly above the product image.

any ideas?

Comment: eh, I'd be ok with the flyout not working in IE6 if it worked in IE7+.  I changed the position to static so you can see better what it's doing in IE7 with the product image (and how it breaks in IE6 too).  Unfortunately it really isn't an option to just tell IE users to screw off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, IE7 was taking a dump over the opacity filter.  I started from scratch and redid everything from the ground up.  I had it working beautifully in both browsers and was wondering what I'd done differently - then I added the opacity filters back in and voila, duplicate results.

I've removed the IE opacity line (below) and all is working beautifully

```
filter:alpha(opacity=92);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you seen suckerfish menus? http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: I think mine is laid out in a very similar way to these. I have a feeling I could drop those in place and still have the same issues (I think it might be something with how the menu interacts with its containers).  I'll give it a shot though.